# Unconventional cake cutting

Tags: geometry, circles, area

Say you have a semicircle (of cake from plan view), and your goal is to divide it in 2 unconventionally (thus the title)...

I'm trying to divide my semicircle in a non-radial way as shown by my image. [image]

What would theta be (as per the image) such that the area of a is equal to that of b? And what is the term for the shape represented by b?

Happy cake cutting to all

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following figure:

[image]

Our goal is to set $\theta$ so that the red area equal the blue area. Since the total of the two is $\frac12r^2\pi$, we want the red area to be $\frac14r^2\pi$.

The well known formula for the red area (the [area of the circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area)) is 
$$\frac12r^2(\beta-\sin\beta).$$

We know that $\beta=\pi-2\theta$ because $\frac{\beta}2+\frac{\pi}2+\theta=\pi.$

So, we have the following equation:

$$\frac14r^2\pi=\frac12r^2(\pi-2\theta-\sin\left(\pi-2\theta\right)).$$

It turns out that the desired value for $\theta$ does not depend on $r$. Finally, after cancelling out $r^2$ the following equation remains to be solved

$$0=4\theta+2\sin(\pi-2\theta)-\pi.$$

This equation cannot be solved easily. Here is, however, a graphical solution

[image]

This figure shows that the solution is somewhere after $0.4$ radian. The solution is the magic angle that solves the problem for every circle.